# Can I transfer the domain and website to Google Domains (google-domains)?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

Can I migrate the domain and website in the wordpress to Google Domains (https://domains.google.com)?

Read the documentation, but still in doubt, Can I migrate a website in wordpress to google domains too?

Comment: Guys, please, not just vote negative. Write what is wrong.
Because I have a doubt and did not find an answer, I posted a question for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open a ticket on the Google Domains support and the answer is:

> It's great to hear that you're interested in transferring your domain
>   and website into Google Domains. However, we're only able to transfer
>   the domain.
>
> The website needs to be with a web hosting provider. Since Google
>   Domains is a registrar, you're more than welcome to have your domain
>   with us.